# highscore update not working in 2dunity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner at 2D Unity game development and this is my first game. In this game I have two scenes - one is playing scene and another is game over scene. When I try to display the high score in game over scene, it is not working for me.  Here is the code I tried:

```
public class highscore : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text hscore;

    private void Start() {
        hscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0).ToString();
    }

    public void Update() {
        if (GetComponent<Score>().score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore")) { 
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", GetComponent<Score>().score);
            hscore.text = GetComponent<Score>().score.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

It freezes the game over scene and nothing else s working on that. Does anyone know what the problem is? Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking at this: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/high-score-playerprefs

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to rework your code completely. For example why do you need additional screen just for a showing the high score. The switching between the scenes is somewhat of a costly operation. And even if you do need two screens You should put the "show high score" logic outside of your update method for sure. Now to the solution:
The easiest way to handle this is by using `PlayerPrefs` to update the high score like so `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", yourScore);` you can get the value like so: 
int `highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);` The second param is optional it's return if there is no `HighScore` set before that. The other thing is that you could use a popup to display the high score. That way you don't have to switch between the scenes.

Comment: i'll try the popup method as you mentioned , thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check unity's PlayerPrefs class:

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

As you can see `GetInt()` and `SetInt()` take a value from a dictionary. You have to save that values on disk to pass them between scenes(or to retrive them when you load your game again).

Are you using `Save()` before unloading the old scene? Also your score is comming from the previous scene? If yes are you using  `DontDestroyOnLoad(Object target)` or its just a script in the "ShowScore" scene? If you don't pass it from the first scene it will just have default values, not your score. Hope i was clear enought.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions , i'll try this `save()` method